# How to write an if-else loop to add a column?

Tags: r

I have this data

```
x1   
1A41 
5D12 
5B21 
8C12
```

I want to add a column x2 to the data that writes A, B, C, or D if x1 contains the respective letter.

```
x1    x2
1A41  A
5D12  D
5B21  B
8C12  C
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use search & replace and remove all letter different from A,B,C & D:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(x1= c("1A41", "5B21", "5D12",  "8C12"))

df$x2 <- gsub('.*([A-D]).*','\\1',df$x1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The most convenient approach would be `str_extract_all` from the "stringr" package:

```
library(stringr)
mydf$x2 <- unlist(str_extract_all(mydf$x1, "[A-Z]"))
#     x1 x2
# 1 1A41  A
# 2 5D12  D
# 3 5B21  B
# 4 8C12  C
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the positions for sure of the letters you could use something like

```
df <- data.frame(x1)
pattern <- '[A-D]'
# match pos for each match
matches <- regexpr(pattern, df$x1)
# extract from match pos to match pos + 1
df$x2 <- substr(df$x1, matches ,matches+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
df$x2 <-substr(df$x1,2,2)
```

You don't need to use `ifelse`.

Comment: Sorry I was over simplifying it. The actual data has the letter in random places. Is there a way to find and match the letter then write it to x2?

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
a1 <- read.table(text=" 
1A41 
5D12 
5B21 
8C12",header=F) 

names(a1) <- c("x1")

a1$x2 <- substr(a1$x1,start=2,stop=2)
> a1
    x1 x2
1 1A41  A
2 5D12  D
3 5B21  B
4 8C12  C
```